Is there a way to count the number of columns returned by a select query
I am executing a select statement which has n nunber of columns selected from various tables.
I would like to know how many columns I am using. Is there a way to find that.?
Ex.
Select 1,2,3 from dual:
This gave me below result.
1 2 3
I want to write some sql which will give the numbe of columns written in select statement.  In this case, I expect output as 3.
Select count ('1','2','3') from dual.
I am getting error.
Any other way to get the results?

You can use XML functionality as following:
SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(column_value)) AS cnt FROM XMLTABLE('//ROW/count(*)' 
  PASSING dbms_xmlgen.GETXMLTYPE(
    'SELECT column_selection FROM some_tables')); 

If you have for examples a table with 3 and another table with 4 columns, following query will return 7:
SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(column_value)) AS cnt FROM XMLTABLE('//ROW/count(*)' 
  PASSING dbms_xmlgen.GETXMLTYPE(
    'SELECT * FROM three INNER JOIN four ON three.col1 = four.col1')); 

The MAX function is required because without it, you will get the number of columns for each row the query finds.
Why that? Well, let's execute a query like this:
SELECT column_value AS cnt FROM XMLTABLE('//ROW' 
  PASSING dbms_xmlgen.GETXMLTYPE('
  SELECT 1,2,3 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,5,6 FROM dual'));

This will produce a result like this:



CNT




<x0031>1</x0031><x0032>2</x0032><x0033>3</x0033>


<x0031>4</x0031><x0032>5</x0032><x0033>6</x0033>



Therefore you need both COUNT and MAX to produce the intended outcome.
See this sample fiddle with some other queries and attempts that show the idea and prove it works as expected.

NULL columns are not included, so the result may not be correct: it will be the greatest number of columns NOT NULL among the rows in the dataset returned.

@p3consulting Good hint, thank you. If they really consider this as an issue, they can follow this answer to solve that. Simpler would be to do not use nullable columns. I'm no fan of them, especially not in Oracle.

with
function get_column_count(p_query in clob) return number is
    v_cursor sys_refcursor;
    v_cursor_number integer;
    v_column_count number;
    v_describe_table dbms_sql.desc_tab;
begin
    open v_cursor for p_query;
    v_cursor_number := sys.dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(v_cursor);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns(
        c       => v_cursor_number,
        col_cnt => v_column_count,
        desc_t  => v_describe_table 
    );
    dbms_sql.close_cursor( v_cursor_number );
    return v_column_count;
end;
select get_column_count(q'[ select 1,2,3 from dual ]') column_count
from dual
/

This answer is based on the PL/SQL code in this answer, but used in a PL/SQL WITH clause. Although the answer users PL/SQL, it's still a "pure" SQL statement as far as any SQL client can tell.

Maybe this is what you want to get:
with cols as (select 'Select 1,2,3 from dual' query from dual)
  select count(regexp_substr (query,'[^,]+',1,level)) columns
  from cols connect by level <= length(query) - length(replace(query, ',')) + 1;

   COLUMNS
----------
         3

